# How to place a text inside the top-left corner border of div

Tags: html, css

I've been going through lot of articles about placing a label/legend/text on the border of a div. I've a lot of div where I want to show the different labels exactly like the image shown below:

[image]

As I can see in the w3school they say to have a field set and get declare legend to display the texts, but its not working out for me. I have a set of jquery codes which appends the html with the labels :

```js
$('.menu').hover(function () {
  $(this).css('border', 'solid 2px #8080ff');
  $(this).find('.divlabel').show();
}, function () {
  $(this).css('border', 'none');
  $(this).find('.divlabel').hide();
});
```

```css
.divlabel {
  float: left;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="divlabel">Menu</div>
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
```

Its not working as desired, please help out guys with this css.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: Set position absolute for .divlabel , and top:0 , left:0

Comment: Make the menu absolute and its parent relative like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/L9yeu1s1/)

Comment: I can't understand what's the problem!! check this out http://jsbin.com/gilejuhiju/edit?html,output

Comment: @SandeepNayak: It worked with position relative. Thanks.

Comment: @JayMar: I was using bootstrap right menu, and `.divlabel` was coinciding with the css of `.menu`. Sorry I didn't mentioned that, but anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need jQuery at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example can help you get started. A CSS only solution

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
}
div.wrapper label {
  color: white;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  /* Adjust these values to posiytion the title or label */
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Menu 1</label>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Menu 2</label>
  <div>
    Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Menu 3</label>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Menu 4</label>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Menu 5</label>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>Menu 6</label>
  <div>Suspendisse dui purus, scelerisque at, vulputate vitae, pretium mattis, nunc. Mauris eget neque at sem venenatis eleifend. Ut nonummy.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML5 `data-*` attribute to achieve this. It will save one `div` element:

```css
body {
  font: 14px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.menu {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #8fdaf9;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}
.menu:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  background: #8fdaf9;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" data-title="Menu">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: `data-title`/`dataTitle` was not working at all for me in React. It showed it was applied to my `div` tag in Chrome Dev Tools so I think I configured it OK, but it simply wasn't doing anything. I got rid of the `data-title` attribute altogether and just did `content: 'myStringHere'` and it worked great! Thanks so much--this response led me to just what I wanted: https://i.ibb.co/Q8rSnS0/22.png